# How can we control the location of ticks in BarLegend?

Tags: plotting, legending

I have this `BarLegend` and want to add `Ticks` at the middle of each small color bar in the `BarLegend`

```
BarLegend[{Blend[{Red, Yellow, Brown, Blue, Green, Black}, #] &, {0, 
   1}}, 5, Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

I want to add ticks similar to this

[image]

here is my try but did not work.

```
BarLegend[{Blend[{Red, Yellow, Brown, Blue, Green, Black}, #] &, {0,1}}, 5,Ticks -> {{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, "0.2"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.6,"0.6"}, {0.8, "0.8"}, {1,"1.0"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think that you can do this. By definition, the lowest edge corresponds to the lowest value und correspondingly for the upper edge.

Comment: but there should be some workarounds!

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you might consider

```
SwatchLegend[{Red, Yellow, Brown, Blue, Darker@Green, Black},
  Style[#, Bold] & /@ {"0.0", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, "1.0"},
  LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn",
  LegendMarkerSize -> 40
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: what if I have 4 colors like `BarLegend[{Blend[{Red, Yellow, Black, Blue}, #] &, {0, 1}}, 5, 
 Ticks -> {{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, "0.2"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.6, "0.6"}, {0.8,
     "0.8"}, {1, "1.0"}}]` OR  `BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, 5, 
 Ticks -> {{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, "0.2"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.6, "0.6"}, {0.8,
     "0.8"}, {1, "1.0"}}]`

Answer (score 3):

Here I managed to do it like

```
BarLegend[{Blend[{{0, Red}, {0.2, Red}, {0.201, Yellow}, {0.4, 
      Yellow}, {0.401, Brown}, {0.6, Brown}, {0.601, Blue}, {0.8, 
      Blue}, {0.801, Darker@Green}, {1, Darker@Green}, {1, 
      Black}, {0.2, Black}}, #] &, {0, 1.2}}, 
 Ticks -> Table[{i + 0.1, ToString[NumberForm[i, {2, 1}]]}, {i, 0, 1, 
    0.2}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", Black, FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image]

I would appreciate it if you have an elegant way to do it automatically.

Now, my problem is that if we don't specify each color, e.g.

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, 5,   Ticks -> {{0, "0.0"}, {0.2, "0.2"}, {0.4, "0.4"}, {0.6, "0.6"}, {0.8,      "0.8"}, {1, "1.0"}}]
```

[image]

How can I do it now?